# Required String parameter error on spring

Tags: java, spring, url

I am getting `Required String parameter` error if the value contains %, Could you please let me know why this is happening and a solution for this

For example if my url is `localhost:8080/getsearchresult?searchparam=test` it works

But if pass % in url, spring gives me error

```
localhost:8080/getsearchresult?searchparam=%
```

then getting error and error is `Required String parameter searchparam`

Could you please let me know the reason behind this and would be great if suggest some solution for this

Comment: The problem is not in Spring side but a lack of understanding how URLs are created.

Comment: `%` is a special character. You'll need to encode it.

Comment: URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits. So % is like a reserved character for url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is an incomplete URL. `%` is a special symbol used in [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp):

> URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits

Not only that, but `%` itself is an unsafe ASCII.

If you want to try sending `%` as URL parameter, use `%25`:

```
localhost:8080/getsearchresult?searchparam=%25
```